Flutter native Splash not changing background to white in dark mode
I am a Flutter developer, I am developing an application in which I have to add a splash screen, I am using the flutter native splash Package which is recommended. I am facing an issue which is I am trying to change the background color in splash screen for dark mode which in my case has to be white. but I have tried multiple times my background color is not changing. I am developing application on a windows machine and testing my application on a Xiaomi Redmi Note 12. However when I try other color they work fine but when I change color to white it does not work, help please Below I am attaching .yaml code
flutter_native_splash:
  android: true
  ios: true
  web: false
 
  color: "#fffff"
  image: "lib/assets/app_icon/splash.png"
  color_dark: "#fffff"
  image_dark: "lib/assets/app_icon/splash.png"

android_12:
    image: "lib/assets/app_icon/splash.png"
    color: "#ffffff"
    image_dark: assets/android12splash-invert.png
    color_dark: "#ffffff"

I tried above configurations but it is not doing anything if Change color_dark then it works, for example if use c47272 this color code then it works fine.

I see several things you can try:
 android: true
  ios: true
  web: false
 
  color: "#fffff"
  image: "lib/assets/app_icon/splash.png"
  color_dark: "#fffff"
  image_dark: "lib/assets/app_icon/splash.png"

android_12:
    image: "lib/assets/app_icon/splash.png"
    color: "#ffffff"
    image_dark: assets/android12splash-invert.png
    color_dark: "#ffffff"

First off, the image_dark in the second is not between quotes and I am guessting you mean the lib/assets folder.
So image_dark:
image_dark: "lib/assets/android12splash-invert.png"

Secondly, I think you are missing one F. You need 6 of those, and I only count 5.
So the entire thing:
flutter_native_splash:

  android: true
  ios: true
  web: false
 
  color: "#ffffff"
  image: "lib/assets/app_icon/splash.png"
  color_dark: "#ffffff"
  image_dark: "lib/assets/app_icon/splash.png"

android_12:
    image: "lib/assets/app_icon/splash.png"
    color: "#ffffff"
    image_dark: "lib/assets/android12splash-invert.png"
    color_dark: "#ffffff"

